# How do I print a QLabel?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to print a QLabel from a combobox in QT. Code looks like this:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QWidget w;

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(&w);
QLabel *label = new QLabel("Here you will see the selected text from ComboBox", &w);
QComboBox *combo = new QComboBox(&w);
layout->addWidget(label);
layout->addWidget(combo);
Q_FOREACH(QSerialPortInfo port, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
    combo->addItem(port.portName());

QObject::connect(combo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(QString)), label, (SLOT(setText(QString))));
```

How do i print the label via cout?

Comment: Are you just looking for `std::cout << label->text().toStdString();`?

Comment: Exactly that - now i just need to know, how do i make it print every time i choose another item in the list?

Comment: Connect the [currentTextChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentTextChanged) signal to a function/lambda/slot that prints the text. Connecting to functions/lambdas cannot be done with the old macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT`, you will need to use [the new syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) for that.

Comment: I can't just save the label as a string and print that?

Comment: Well you can print the label text, but that doesn't do the *"every time i choose another item in the list"* part.

Comment: What would the code be for manually printing the label text? Thanks for helping me, by the way. I'm really new to this whole Qt thing!

Comment: @nwp It **can** be done with the old syntax, it just requires that the receiving function is a slot. The new syntax is only required if using free functions or lambdas and there are absolutely nothing requiring free functions or lambdas for printing a string when a combobox changes. Yet I agree that using a lambda is simpler, but the choice still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be using Qt4, let's port that to Qt5 and a newer C++, shall we?

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtSerialPort>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QWidget w;

   auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(&w);
   auto label = new QLabel("Here you will see the selected text from ComboBox");
   auto combo = new QComboBox;
   layout->addWidget(label);
   layout->addWidget(combo);
   for (auto port : QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
       combo->addItem(port.portName());

   QObject::connect(combo, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, [label, combo](){
       label->setText(combo->currentText());
       qDebug() << combo->currentText();
   });

   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

- Try to not use Q_FOREACH in new code, it will [probably be removed in the future](https://www.kdab.com/goodbye-q_foreach/),
- Use `auto` when the type will be already specified by the new operator, this simplifies code,
- Use `qDebug` to output debug information to the terminal,
- Use lambdas in connections when the invoked code is short,
- Use the [new style connections](http://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) for connections, because they will guarantee that your code actually works, the old style has runtime checks, and the new has build time checks.